# Find the range of $x$ for which the sequence $\dfrac{n!} {k!(n-k)!}x^n $ converges to $0$ for a stabilised $k\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm studying in preparation for a Mathematical Analysis I examination and I'm solving past exam exercises.
*If it's any indicator of difficulty, the exercise is Exercise 1 of 4, part $c$ and graded for 7%, so it's supposed to be pretty easy.*

> Find the range of $x$ for which the sequence $\dfrac{n!} {k!(n-k)!}x^n$ converges to $0$ for a stabilised $k\in\mathbb{N}$

I "solved" it by stating that $\dfrac{n!} {k!(n-k)!}={n \choose k}$ is always a positive integer for natural $n,k$.

Following that, by De L'Hospital's theorem the exponential $x^n$ defines the limit. For $x<1$ the sequence converges.

**Would this simple solution be adequate?** Have I missed anything or is there a certain methodology I should be following instead of simple thoughts, to come to an adequate solution?

Comment: Is "stabilized $k"=\,$ constant $\,k\,$ ? And what you state should be $\;\binom nk x^n\;$ and not merely $\;\binom nk\;$ , so the resulting limit is not that trivial.

Comment: Hint: $\binom{n}{k}$ is a polynomial of degree $k$ in $n$.

Comment: Ratio Test, converges for $|x|\lt 1$, diverges elsewhere.

Comment: @Joanpemo Yeah, slight mistake there. The exercise mentions "stabilised" in Greek, so I would guess constant indeed, instead I'm missing some special terminology.

Answer (score 1):

An idea: using D'Alembert's test

$$\left|\frac{\binom{n+1}kx^{n+1}}{\binom nk x^n}\right|=|x|\frac{n+1}{n+1-k}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}|x|\implies\text{the infinite series}\; \sum_{n=k}^\infty \binom nk x^n$$

converges iff $\;|x|<1\;$ and thus the series sequence converges to zero